# How to build a tiktok like video upload and video feed function in a react native app?

Tags: database, mongodb, react-native, video-streaming, video-capture

I have no experience or idea about how video upload and streaming works at the backend, and I am trying to build a tiktok-like app, so if you can share directions on how to approach this, where to learn more, where to find resources, what libraries to use, what database to use, or anything that could be helpful, even if one line advice, I would really appreciate that.

I understand there is going to be a lot of code and that could be out of scope here, but any direction/advice would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, could you find any information regarding how they make their videos play quickly?

Comment: HI @EmmanuelGarciaMartinez, they pre-load their videos, so while we are watching the first video, the next two videos are already buffered, and so when we get to the next video it plays fast.

Comment: Do you know any library that I can do or how to make the following videos preload?